# Laravel return results based on user selection

Tags: php, mysql, search, laravel, filter

I have the following

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="symbols[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="symbols[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="symbols[]" value="3" />
etc...
<select name="city">
   <option value="Dublin">Dublin</option>
   <option value="Cork">Cork</option>
   etc ...
</select>
```

Laravel

```
return DB::table('restaurants')
            ->select('restaurants.id as restaurantId',
                    'restaurants.image_id as imageId',
                    'restaurants.name as restaurantName',
                    'restaurants.slug as restaurantSlug',
                    'restaurants.description as restaurantDescription')
            ->leftJoin('restaurants_symbols', 'restaurants_symbols.restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id')
            ->leftJoin('restaurants_locations', 'restaurants_locations.restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id')
            ->groupBy('restaurants_symbols.restaurant_id')
            ->where(function($q) use ($input) {
                $q->whereIn('restaurants_symbols.symbol_id', $input['symbol']);

                if(!empty($input['city'])) {
                    $q->where('restaurants_locations.city', $input['city']);
                }
            })
            ->get();
```

Everything works fine beside the fact that if the user checked value1 and value2, the query returns all restaurants that contain value1 OR value2, so I want to achieve is return only the restaurants that have the symbols representing value1 AND value2 only.

Any suggestions? I was thinking maybe to return the values as they are and then filter them in a foreach loop but I don't know if that it's possible and if it is I don't see the logic of how to do it, any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use forloop for where conditions.Its return value1 and value2 for your case

```
$symbol=$input['symbol'];
    return DB::table('restaurants')
                ->select('restaurants.id as restaurantId',
                        'restaurants.image_id as imageId',
                        'restaurants.name as restaurantName',
                        'restaurants.slug as restaurantSlug',
                        'restaurants.description as restaurantDescription')
                ->leftJoin('restaurants_symbols', 'restaurants_symbols.restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id')
                ->leftJoin('restaurants_locations', 'restaurants_locations.restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id')
                ->groupBy('restaurants_symbols.restaurant_id')
                ->where(function($q) use ($input) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($symbol);$i++)                //add forloop
    {
                    $q->where('restaurants_symbols.symbol_id', $symbol[$i]);
    }

                    if(!empty($input['city'])) {
                        $q->where('restaurants_locations.city', $input['city']);
                    }
                })
                ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I tried it and I get back an error "Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: Post your array of $input['symbol']

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(2) "29" }

Comment: I did and the error has gone but if I check more than 1 checkbox it brings no results

Comment: print_r(DB::getQueryLog()); after the query.Its return what return what query is we execute.

Comment: you can find the result here, cause it's too long for a comment http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNjOoO

Comment: replace ? with correct array value and paste query to sql section in your database.this query is corrext

Comment: I don't get it, so if the query it's correct, why I don't get the results?

Comment: check that your table if values are present or not the query condition

Comment: I've tried everything, rewrite all code, checked database, the values are there in all tables the way they're meant to be and it's the same problem, if I check only 1 checkbox it's working just fine, once I've selected more than one it brings and empty array